# Breaking Up a Formatted Number

Tags: php

Let say I have the following formatting number as a string in PHP:

12,345,678.97

How would I break that up in PHP where I would get an array like the following?

```
array
(
  [0] => 12,
  [1] => ',',
  [2] => '345',
  [3] => ',',
  [4] => '678',
  [5] => '.',
  [6] => '97'
);
```

OR

```
array
(
  [0] => 97,
  [1] => '.',
  [2] => '678',
  [3] => ',',
  [4] => '345',
  [5] => ',',
  [6] => '12'
);
```

I basically want to break up the string so that numbers are broken by groups and also the characters that are between groups of numbers are broken out too.  I need to do this in order to automatically determine the thousands/decimal separator in PHP for currency strings.

Comment: Why do you need to determine these separators in the first place? Usually, if at all possible, you should be working with proper internal int/float/currency values, and format them only when outputting them. What is your use case here?

Comment: @Pekka: The OP explained why...

Comment: @Oli where does he explain why?

Comment: There might be cases where I need to take an already formatted number and conver it to another currency's display.

Comment: @Pekka: "*I need to do this in order to automatically determine...*".  I'm assuming he/she gets the user to type in a number representation, which he/she then wants to parse in order to format all numbers accordingly.

Comment: @Oli maybe. I'm interested in why exactly - it might turn out that it can be circumvented, which would be much better. Parsing arbitrary formatted currency values is full of problems

Answer (score 4):

Using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) will work good in this case:

```
// Split at any non-number
$arr = preg_split('/(\D)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check in to `number_format` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to solve the problem. Already built in to PHP :)

Also found `money_format` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)